# Trailing Zero in Double Variable using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, int, double

I want to add trailing zero in my double variable

example is:
if user enter 1 then it's automatically add trailing zero like **1.0000000**  but must in Double Variable which always stuck because i want to send this double variable to the webservices.

String Format do resolve this issue but when i convert string to Double by explict conversion then it's again 1.0 only kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Since the web service is probably expecting "text", why not format the value as you want and simply append it to the text...?

Comment: You can send text in webservice

Comment: basically i want to stringfy the Codble Structure the param is double but send the server to Stringfy object so i must need double value to concat trailing zero

Comment: You will need a custom encoder that will convert the double to a string during the codification phase.  There are many tutorials on how to use custom codable, such as https://possiblemobile.com/2018/04/swift-codable-protocol-part-i/

Answer (score 0):

I make up a logic and it's work first i send the string to encode the structure after getting the json i do stringfy and replace those string by finding occurrence and then remove the string double quotes to and make it double value and then send the Payload.

Thanks all commenters...